# remove /admin from address and direct to subdomain keeping path

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes

I'm having difficulty directing the admin address to the sub domain, I did a nice search but everything became more confusing. In short, I need to remove the domain.com/admin to the subdomain admin.dominio.com keeping the rest of the address so that there is no conflict or that it gets lost kkkkk

routes admin

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    /*authentication*/
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth', 'prefix' => 'auth', 'as' => 'auth.'], function () {
        Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
        Route::post('login', 'LoginController@submit')->middleware('actch');
        Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    });
```

routes web/user

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('terms-and-conditions', 'HomeController@terms_and_conditions')->name('terms-and-conditions');
Route::get('about-us', 'HomeController@about_us')->name('about-us');
Route::get('contact-us', 'HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact-us');
Route::get('privacy-policy', 'HomeController@privacy_policy')->name('privacy-policy');
Route::post('newsletter/subscribe', 'NewsletterController@newsLetterSubscribe')->name('newsletter.subscribe');
Route::get('authentication-failed', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: That's right, it didn't resolve the issue.